# Azure pipeline release deploy xml transformation question

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an azure web site, and an application that i have set up via VSTS to build/release to this site.  I'm using the Azure app service deploy task ( https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/README.md ) and i need to be able to transform the web.config based on library variable settings.

The basic transformations are easy, i have no problem just replacing the connection strings and the app settings.  There are however, more difficult settings that i need to change.  for example:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"/>

<sessionState  mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisStateStore" cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="RedisStateStore" applicationName="XXX" type="YYY"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>

<sessionState cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" mode="Custom" customProvider="SqlSessionStateProviderAsync">
      <providers>
<add name="SqlSessionStateProviderAsync" connectionStringName="SQLSessionConnectionString" type="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SqlSessionStateProviderAsync, Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SqlSessionStateProviderAsync, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

based on settings in my deployment library variables, i need to be able to configure the session state to be one of the three above, and edit the appropriate settings accordingly (the variables inside the redis  provider for example can change.

Additionally i need to edit more files than just the web.config.  What are good ways to do this?